# Freemarker: iterating nested list in hash

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, freemarker

I want to iterate a List nested in a Map, the data structure is like:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> groups = new TreeMap<>()
// Some code else to put values into groups ...
```

Freemarker template:

```
<#list groups?keys as groupKey>
    ${groupKey}    // It's OK here.
    <#list groups[groupKey] as item>  // Exception threw here, detail message is pasted below
        ${item}
    </#list>
</#list>
```

Detail exception message:

> FreeMarker template error:
>   For "...[...]" left-hand operand: Expected a sequence or string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), but this evaluated to an extended_hash (wrapper: f.t.SimpleHash):
>   ==> groups

So, what is the problem?

**P.S.**

I have tried `groups.get(groupKey)` instead of `groups[groupKey]`, it throws a new Exception stack:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
java.lang.String.compareTo(String.java:108)
java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:346)
java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:273)
freemarker.template.SimpleHash.get(SimpleHash.java:160)
freemarker.core.Dot._eval(Dot.java:40)
freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:76)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem in the original question is that FTL's hash type is not like `Map`. It's a collection of "variables", that is, the keys must be `String`-s. (Even that `?keys` works is a glitch in `BeansWrapper`... though now it comes handy.) Since the key is a number, FTL assumes that you want to get an item from a sequence (a `List` or array), or that you want to get a character from a string, hence the original error message.

The solution is using the Java API-s, like `get` in Dev-an's answer. (On the long term FTL meant to introduce the map type, so all this problems with non-string keys will end, but who knows when that will be...)

**Update:** Since 2.3.22 there's `?api` to access the Java API of objects, like `myMap?api.get(nonStringKey)`. However, it's by default not allowed (see the `api_builtin_enabled` configuration setting and more in the Manual: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_buitin_api_and_has_api). Also note that as Java maps are particular about the numerical type, if the key is not an `Integer` coming from a Java, you have to use `myMap?api.get(myNumericalKey?int)`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I changed the `groupKey`'s type from `Integer` to `String`, and it worked.

Comment: So what was the solution? I am having the same problem and not able to catch up with your solution.

Comment: @Mohy: What do you mean? `?api` doesn't work for some reason?

Comment: My case was a bit different. I was looping through the map twice, that produced the exact error above. Very wired and does not make sense to me, but once I removed my second iteration everything works.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
<#list groups?keys as groupKey>
    ${groupKey}
    <#list groups.get(groupKey) as item>
        ${item}
    </#list>
</#list>
```

Comment: I have tried this, and it shows another exception: `nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String`. I have no idea where this Cast occurred.

Comment: It occurs inside `TreeMap`, as the stack trace shows, so. don't you have a `String` key in that `TreeMap` somewhere?

Comment: Perhaps FTL takes `groupKey` as a String key and threw this exception. Finally, after I changed the type of `groups` to `Map<Integer, List<String>>`, it worked.